# No me aparece la ventana del emulador de android en ionic. parte II

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, emulación

Estoy tratando de emular una app en android:
1º Voy a la carpeta donde tengo mi proyecto, para ello escribo en mi línea de comandos `cd rutademiproyecto`
2º Escribo los siguientes comandos:

- `ionic cordova platform add android`
- `ionic cordova build android`
- `ionic cordova emulate android`

Después de que se haya finalizado el procesamiento de la última sentencia de la anterior lista de sentencias, no veo por ningún lado una ventana con una emulación de android. **¿Ya que se supone que debería aparecerme una ventana con el sistema operativo android, no?**
Estoy siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QepxfadRc3Y&list=PLYPjmy5IVxT-7FV0uzpG2izFhGoE0Hq2y&index=5), y ahí veo que se aparece una ventanta para el sistema operativo ios, el minuto 5:50.
No sé si mi problema tiene algo que ver con uno de los mensajes que me lanza Ionic a través de la consola, en concreto con este:

> CordovaError: No emulator images (avds) found.

Por si sirve de algo a continuación escribo todos los mensajes que me lanza Ionic através de la consola cuando escribo `ionic cordova emulate android`:

> Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
>   [21:08:04]  build dev started ... [21:08:08]  clean started ...
>   [21:08:09]  clean finished in 836 ms [21:08:09]  copy started ...
>   [21:08:12]  deeplinks started ... [21:08:12]  deeplinks finished in
>   131 ms [21:08:12]  transpile started ... [21:09:19]  transpile
>   finished in 66.93 s [21:09:19]  preprocess started ... [21:09:19] 
>   preprocess finished in 1 ms [21:09:19]  webpack started ... [21:09:22]
>   copy finished in 72.92 s [21:09:41]  webpack finished in 22.57 s
>   [21:09:41]  sass started ... Without `from` option PostCSS could
>   generate wrong source map and will not find
>   Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file path or to `undefined` to
>   prevent this w
>   arning. [21:09:56]  sass finished in 14.85 s [21:09:56]  postprocess
>   started ... [21:09:57]  postprocess finished in 497 ms [21:09:57] 
>   lint started ... [21:09:57]  build dev finished in 112.93 s
>
> > cordova emulate android [21:10:02]  lint finished in 5.79 s Android Studio project detected
>
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk-windows JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 studio Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject
>   Path: app Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
>   publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All
>   variants are now
>   published. The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be re
>   moved in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>           at build_c43z9qtayi62ulxyg0zehvtr5.run(C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\ap 
>   p\build.gradle:143) :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
>
> UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig  UP-TO-DATE
>
> :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest
>
> UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:processDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:preBuild  UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAidl  UP-TO-DATE :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript
>   NO-SOURCE :app:compileDebugRenderscript  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig 
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues 
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources
>
> UP-TO-DATE :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest  UP-TO-DATE :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug 
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk
>
> NO-SOURCE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders
>
> UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders  UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>
> :app:transformClassesWithStackFramesFixerForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
>
> UP-TO-DATE :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk  NO-SOURCE
>   :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug 
>   UP-TO-DATE
>
> :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes  NO-SOURCE
>
> :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug  UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateSigningDebug
>
> :app:packageDebug
>
> :app:assembleDebug
>
> :app:cdvBuildDebug
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 8s 46 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 43
>   up-to-date Built the following apk(s):
>           C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\android-sdk-windows JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161 (node:6996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   CordovaError: No emulator images (
>   avds) found.
>   1. Download desired System Image by running: "C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\andro
>   id.bat" sdk
>   2. Create an AVD by running: "C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\android.bat" avd HINT: For a faster
>   emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM devi
>   ce driver
>
> ```
> at C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\emulator.js:288:29
> at _fulfilled (C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:85
> ```
>
> 4:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_mo
>   dules\q\q.js:883:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\n
>   ode_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
>       at C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
>       at runSingle (C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137
>   :13)
>       at flush (C:\RedditApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:176:11) (node:6996) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch
>   block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().
>   (rejection
>   id: 1) (node:6996) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are depre
>   cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
>   terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>
> [OK] Your app has been deployed.
>        Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

Answer (score 0):

Antes de intentar emular en ionic, abre android studio, te creas un proyecto en blanco. Ve a la pestaña Tools > AVD Manager. Cuando lo tengas abierto le das a Create virtual device. Yo tengo 2 virtual devices: un Pixel y una tablet Pixel para emular las apps en Tablet y mobil. Una vez hayas hecho esto, debería funcionarte ya sin ese error.

Básicamente lo que pasa es que al intentar ejecutar el emulador no encuentra una maquina virtual en la que "deployear".